# Append html table on Button Click

Tags: c#, html, append, buttonclick

I want to append html table in a div on button click. I have the following Code but Its is not being fired. Can anyone help

C# Code

```
      html.Append("< table >");
        html.AppendFormat("<tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColName' style='width: 250px;'>Full Name</td>");
        html.AppendFormat("<td class='logsColValue'><asp:TextBox ID='FullName' runat='server' Width='250px'></ asp:TextBox > </td>");
        html.AppendFormat("</tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColName'>ID Type</td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColValue'><asp:DropDownList ID='BA_IDType' class='chosen - select form - control' Width='250px' runat='server'></asp:DropDownList></td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("</tr>");
        html.AppendFormat(" < tr> ");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColName'>ID Number</td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColValue'><asp:TextBox ID='IDNumber' runat='server' Width='250px'></asp:TextBox></td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("</tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColName'>ID Expiry Date</td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColValue'><asp:TextBox ID='IDExpityDate' runat='server' Width='250px'></asp:TextBox></td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("</tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< tr>");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColName'>Investor Number</td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("< td class='logsColValue'><asp:TextBox ID='InvestorNumber' runat='server' Width='250px'></asp:TextBox></td> ");
        html.AppendFormat("</tr>");
        html.Append("  </table> ");
```

New_BM.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() } );

Comment: You should use grid view for displaying table structure. You are reinventing wheel.

Comment: how can I do that @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: you can use asp.net grid view from this link: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70

Comment: You need to read about it. There are tons of blogs and articles available on internet. Search it on Google and you will find them.